# Multiple UpsertDEs not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a journey and want to mark every time a user receives an email. To do that I created a data extension to populate and a function to change the status of the user from false to true.  My problem comes when I reset the status of the user in the first mail of the journey using this function:

```ampscript
%%[ 
set @formatFecha = Format(@from, "dd/MM/yy")
set @fechaVuelo=  DateParse(@formatFecha,0)

InsertDE("Fecha_Vuelo","SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr, "Date", @fechaVuelo, "EventDate", NOW() )

UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV1","TRUE")
UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV1R","FALSE")
UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV2","FALSE")
UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV2R","FALSE")
UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV3","FALSE")

]%%
```

The rest of the emails in the journey have a simple version of this code and works fine:

```ampscript
%%[ 

UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV2","TRUE")

]%%
```

**¡¡Well after checking all our code we notice that is the format date funtion the one that crete the problem!!!!, and we just saw about a debug but we are not sure if it´s necessary in this part:**

````ampscript
%%[
set @formatFecha = Format(@from, "mm/dd/yy")
set @fechaVuelo= DateParse(@formatFecha,0)



InsertDE("Fecha_Vuelo","SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr, "Date", @fechaVuelo, "EventDate", NOW() )]%% ```

and now we are just trying to figured out why is this a problem....
````

Comment: What's not working?  None of the flags get updated?

Comment: Do you want to create multiple rows with the upserts or just populate multiple `EmailV...` columns in a single DE record?

Comment: the thing is that this piece of code stop the sending of the first mail in the journey, actually, this get update but If I don´t recieve the first email the status true or false doesnt reset in the data ext.

Comment: well... we just discover that the part of the code that block our journey is the format of the date

Answer (score 1):

Since it is for all the same Subscriber on the same DE, you do not need to do multiple calls, you can just combine it all into a single Upsert.

There are some caching and processing issues with doing multiple update/insert/lookups to a record in the same DE in an email, so hopefully this will resolve that 'eccentric' behavior by having all in one.

So could change to like so:

```ampscript
%%[ 
set @formatFecha = Format(@from, "dd/MM/yy")
set @fechaVuelo=  DateParse(@formatFecha,0)

InsertDE("Fecha_Vuelo","SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr, "Date", @fechaVuelo, "EventDate", NOW() )

UpsertDE("Carrito_JB_SendLogs", 1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailV1","TRUE","EmailV1R","FALSE","EmailV2","FALSE","EmailV2R","FALSE","EmailV3","FALSE")

]%%
```

And that should then hit all of the fields in a single call to update them.

Answer (score 0):

we solved!
the problem comes from the data, our clinet send us multiples formats of dates, that is why the format formula and the dateParse one where not working.

To solve this we destroy the date and then we created again in the format that we need, this is the formula we use based on length:

```
%%[

if length(@from) == 8 AND  @language != "en" then
 
     SET @Month = Substring(@from,4,2)
     SET @Day = Substring(@from,1,2)
     SET @Year = Substring(@from,7,2)
     SET @StringDate = Concat('20',@Year,'-',@Month,'-',@Day)
     SET @fechaVuelo= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDate)), "MM/dd/yy")
        UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVuelo,"EventDate",NOW())

elseif length(@from) == 7 AND  @language != "en" then
  SET @Month7 = Substring(@from,3,2)
  SET @Day7 = Substring(@from,1,1)
  SET @Year7 = Substring(@from,6,2)
SET @StringDate7 = Concat('20',@Year7,'-',@Month7,'-',@Day7)
 SET @fechaVuelo7= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDate7)), "MM/dd/yy")
 UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVuelo7,"EventDate",NOW()) 


elseif  length(@from) == 6 AND  @language != "en" then
  SET @Month6 = Substring(@from,0,1)
  SET @Day6 = Substring(@from,3,1)
  SET @Year6 = Substring(@from,5,2)
  SET @StringDate6 = Concat('20',@Year6,'-','0',@Month6,'-','0',@Day6)
  SET @fechaVuelo6= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDate6)), "MM/dd/yy")
UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVuelo6,"EventDate",NOW())

elseif  length(@from) == 10 AND  @language != "en" then
  SET @Month10 = Substring(@from,4,2)
  SET @Day10 = Substring(@from,1,2)
  SET @Year10 = Substring(@from,7,4)
SET @StringDate10 = Concat(@Year10,'-',@Month10,'-',@Day10)
SET @fechaVuelo10= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDate10)), "MM/dd/yy")
UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVuelo10,"EventDate",NOW())

<!--fecha en language EN -->
elseif length(@from) == 8 AND  @language == "en" then
 
     SET @DayEN = Substring(@from,4,2)
     SET @MonthEN = Substring(@from,1,2)
     SET @YearEN = Substring(@from,7,2)
     SET @StringDateEN = Concat('20',@YearEN,'-',@MonthEN,'-',@DayEN)
     SET @fechaVueloEN= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDateEN)), "MM/dd/yy")
     UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVueloEN,"EventDate",NOW())

elseif length(@from) == 6 AND  @language == "en" then
  SET @MonthEN6 = Substring(@from,0,1)
  SET @DayEN6 = Substring(@from,3,1)
  SET @YearEN6 = Substring(@from,5,2)
  SET @StringDateEN6 = Concat('20',@YearEN6,'-','0',@MonthEN6,'-','0',@DayEN6)
  SET @fechaVueloEN6= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDateEN6)), "MM/dd/yy")
UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVueloEN6,"EventDate",NOW())


elseif length(@from) == 7 AND  @language == "en" then
  SET @MonthEN7 = Substring(@from,0,1)
  SET @DayEN7 = Substring(@from,3,2)
  SET @YearEN7 = Substring(@from,6,2)
  SET @StringDateEN7 = Concat('20',@YearEN7,'-','0',@MonthEN7,'-',@DayEN7)
  SET @fechaVueloEN7= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDateEN7)), "MM/dd/yy")
UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVueloEN7,"EventDate",NOW())

elseif  length(@from) == 10 AND  @language == "en" then
  SET @Day10 = Substring(@from,4,2)
  SET @Month10 = Substring(@from,1,2)
  SET @Year10 = Substring(@from,7,4)
SET @StringDate10 = Concat(@Year10,'-',@Month10,'-',@Day10)
SET @fechaVuelo10= FormatDate(DateParse(v(@StringDate10)), "MM/dd/yy")
UpsertDE("NEW_Fecha_Vuelo",1,"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,"EmailAddress",emailaddr,"Date",@fechaVuelo10,"EventDate",NOW())

Endif

]%%
```